# May the heat kernel of a connection Laplacian vanish?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, parabolic-pde, laplacian, heat-equation

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold and $E \to M$ be a Hermitian bundle. If $\nabla$ is a Hermitian connection on $E$, one may define the Laplacian $L = \nabla^* \nabla$, and then consider its Friedrichs extension, that we shall also denote $L$. The "heat" semigroup $t \mapsto \exp(-tL)$ has a smooth "heat" kernel $h$ such that $h(t,x,y) : E_x \to E_y$ is a linear map for every $(t, x, y) \in (0, \infty) \times M \times M$ (where $E_x$ is the fiber over $x \in M$).

> 1. Is it possible that $h(t,x,y) = 0$ for *some* $(t,x,y)$?
> 2. If yes, is it possible that $h(t,x,y) = 0$ for *some* $(t,x) \in (0, \infty) \times M$ and $y$ in *some open* subset $U_{t,x}$?

I am mostly interested in the case $E = M \times \mathbb C$ and $\nabla = \mathrm d + A \wedge$ (with $A$ an imaginary $1$-form).

I know that the answer is negative for the "usual" Laplace-Beltrami operator (corresponding to $A=0$), but the proof of this makes use of the parabolic maximum principle, which in turn depends on $h$ having real (in fact non-negative) values. When $A$ is imaginary, though, $h$ may take complex values, and most techniques from the case $A=0$ are lost.

Comment: Have you tried looking at parabolic unique continuation results for your second question.? Those are quite robust (e.g. work for systems).

Comment: for the case you are interested in, if I understand your notations, it seems to me that the leading term of L should be an elliptic operator, which might help.

Comment: @ThomasRichard: Yes, both $L$ and its principal part are elliptic, but otherwise your comment is a bit enigmatic. Could you please clarify it a bit?

Comment: @RBega2: I do not come from the PDE "camp", therefore I do not follow you. Could you be a bit more explicit please?

Comment: An analytic function has the property that if it vanishes to infinity order at a point, then it vanishes identically in the appropriate component of its domain.  This property is called the unique continuation property and turns out to hold for solutions of a general class of elliptic (and parabolic) equations (the point being that for solutions of an elliptic equation with analytic coefficients the solution is also analytic, but this property holds for rougher coefficients ).  This paper https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.afm/1485898790 addresses the parabolic setting (so should apply to $h$).